# Partial Correlation Matrix controlling for one variable

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, partial

I'm currently trying to do a pairwise correlation matrix in R using the ppcor package.

It appears that when I feed a dataframe into the pcor function it produces estimates of x and y, controlling for all other variables (z).

Is there a method of producing the pairwise matrix with x and y controlling for a single variable z ?

If not, is there another package that can get this done?

Comment: you could try isolating them and then create correlation tables